# read a file from line 1-6 then 6-12 etc and compare one column to see if they have same version

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file which is sorted as per the below;

```
ENVTEST_SG CPSG01 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST_ATS CP01 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST_CC CPMTECH01 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST_BI CPBI01 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST_SER CPSER01 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST_YAAN CPYAAN01 1.1.11.0
<Space added here for clear viewing>
ENVTEST1_ATS CP02 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST1_CC CPMTECH02 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST1_BI CPBI02 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST1_SER CPSER02 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST1_SG CPSG02 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST1_YAAN CPYAAN02 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST2_ATS CP03 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST2_SG CPSG03 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST2_SER CPSER03 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST2_CC CPMTECH03 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST2_YAAN CPYAAN03 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST2_BI CPBI03 1.1.10.3
<Space added here for clear viewing>
ENVTEST3_ATS CP04 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST3_CC CPMTECH04 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST3_SG CPSG04 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST3_SER CPSER04 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST3_BI CPBI04 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST3_YAAN CPYAAN04 1.1.10.3
```

As can be seen in the file, there are three environments; ENVTEST, ENVTEST1, ENVTEST2 etc. Each env has 6 lines relating to its version number.

What I need to be able to do is, for each SPECIFIC system check if all users (second column $2/CCPSG01 etc) version numbers are the same. If they are the same just print out ONE env, user and version for that system. For example;

```
ENVTEST_SG CPSG01 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST_ATS CP01 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST_CC CPMTECH01 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST_BI CPBI01 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST_SER CPSER01 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST_YAAN CPYAAN01 1.1.11.0
```

First, I want to check for that ENV if the 6 users have the same version. If they do, then print like this;

ENVTEST_(CAN BE ANY) SIT1 1.1.11.0 (Just want one line of any user for the system).

Please could someone point me in the right direction or help with the issue?? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: awk -F: '{if(!($1==$2||$2==$3||$3==$1))printf("%s","not ");print"matched",$0}' -----------I have tried this but cant seem to read 6 lines and compare the version column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print only those lines which has same version number for specific environment then you can go for below command:

```
awk '{split($1,a,"_"); res[a[1]" "$3]=a[1]"_(CAN BE ANY) SIT1 "$3; cnt[a[1]" "$3]++;} END {for(i in res){if(cnt[i]==6){print res[i]}}}' file
```

It will print:

```
ENVTEST2_(CAN BE ANY) SIT1 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST_(CAN BE ANY) SIT1 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST3_(CAN BE ANY) SIT1 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST1_(CAN BE ANY) SIT1 1.1.10.3
```

If you want to `SIT` to vary according to `ENVTEST` then refer the below command:

```
awk '{split($1,a,"_"); res[a[1]" "$3]=a[1]"_(CAN BE ANY) SIT"substr(a[1],8,9)" "$3; cnt[a[1]" "$3]++;} END {for(i in res){if(cnt[i]==6){print res[i]}}}' file
```

It will print:

```
ENVTEST2_(CAN BE ANY) SIT2 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST_(CAN BE ANY) SIT 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST3_(CAN BE ANY) SIT3 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST1_(CAN BE ANY) SIT1 1.1.10.3
```

Comment: Hi Abhinandan, thank you ever so much for the above response,it works as advised. Can I be a bit cheeky  and ask how can I name each env in the above code. I.e. I want ENTEST2 SIT2 1.1.10.3 and ENVTEST1 SIT1 1.1.10.3 etc. Please could you also explain how the code works? It would be great to understand as opposed to just copying. Once again, I appreciate the help and support recieved. :)

Comment: @junz94 You mean, You don't need "(CAN BE ANY)"?

Comment: It's very difficult for me to understand your expected output.you mentioned your expected output as below:
`CCPTEST6_SG SIT6 1.1.11.1`
`CCPTEST3_SG SIT3 1.1.10.3`
`CCPTEST2_SG SIT3 1.1.10.3`
`CCPTEST9_SG SIT9 1.1.11.1 `
`CCPTEST4_SG SIT4 1.1.11.1 `
`CCPTEST8_SG SIT8 1.1.11.1 `
`CCPTEST5_SG SIT5 1.1.11.0.i5 `
`CCPTEST_SG SIT 1.1.11.0.i5 `
`CCPTEST1_SG SIT1 1.1.10.3 `
`CCPTEST10_SG SIT10 1.1.10.3`
Pardon me but how you drove this output from given input file. I really didn't understand.

Comment: so sorry, my expected output was incorrect. The desired output is;    ENVTEST2_(CAN BE ANY) SIT2 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST_(CAN BE ANY) SIT 1.1.11.0
ENVTEST3_(CAN BE ANY) SIT3 1.1.10.3
ENVTEST1_(CAN BE ANY) SIT1 1.1.10.3          Apologies for the confusion. I extract this information from an oracle database and select the version number for each user (can be any = user) and dump into a text file. The only difference from your orginal answer is that I just want to name the second columns SIT1-10 etc.

Comment: Also I want to add a test into this command. Each ENV has 6 users (ATS,SG etc). I want to test if the version number is the same for each ENV_USER and if so then go and print only 1 line for any user for each env. I.E. ENV1 has 6 users and they all have the same release version, so then the code will print only 1 line for this; ENV1 SIT1 1.1.11.0. However, if one or more user for that ENV is different then throw an error or state that the versions are different. Is this possible?

Comment: @junz94 Updated. Please up vote it if you find it as useful. thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you Abhinandan, I have managed to get my desired output with the below. awk '{split($1,a,"_"); res[a[1]" "$3]=a[1]"_"a[2]" "$3; cnt[a[1]" "$3]++;}END {for(i in res) print "output: " res[i]}' config.txt